# Await For Each Callback

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have an issue where I need to wait for a foreach loop to return each time. I tried placing `await` in some places and tried to use a Promise but I can't get it working. Have a look at the below code to understand my question better.

```js
arr = [1, 2, 3];

MyFunction = async function() {
    arr.forEach(async element => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(element);
        }, 1000); 
    });
    console.log('done');
}

MyFunction();
```

With this code you get:

```
done
1
2
3
```

How do I use `await` or something to make it come out:

```
1
2
3
done
```

Comment: You can't do that with a regular foreach loop, you need to wrap it in a custom recursive function or a similar behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). Essentially, use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on an array to turn it into an array of promises, and then await them all, and then continue execution.

```js
arr = [1, 2, 3];

MyFunction = async function() {
    var promises = arr.map(element => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
              console.log(element);
              resolve();
          }, 1000); 
        });
    });
    
    await Promise.all(promises);
    console.log('done');
}

MyFunction();
```

Comment: Wow this is awesome. Learnt something new today! Thank you!

Comment: `map(async element=>...` why make the iterator an async function? Just like *forEach*, *map* will do nothing with the returned Promise.

Comment: You're right @Kaiido, no async code in there. Updated

Answer (score 0):

Using `async` or `await` does not magically turn a callback based async function into a Promise based you that you could await. So you need to promisify the callback based asnyc code:

```js
return new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(element);
    resolve()
  }, 1000);
})
```

The `arr.forEach` will break the Promise chain as you don't save the Promise created in the arrow function, and as of that you cannot wait for them. So you need to use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```js
arr = [1, 2, 3];

MyFunction = async function() {
  await Promise.all(arr.map(async element => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(element);
        resolve()
      }, 1000);
    })
  }));
  console.log('done');
}

MyFunction();
```

If it is required that the async tasks are done in order then you could use a regular for loop.

```js
arr = [1, 2, 3];

MyFunction = async function() {
  for( let element of arr) {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(element);
        resolve()
      }, 1000);
    })
  }
  console.log('done');
}

MyFunction();
```